# Tensorflow error: expected dense_Dense1_input to have shape [null,3] but got array with shape [3,1]

Tags: javascript, arrays, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a TF model which takes a tensor with [1,3] shape

```
// example: [1,2,3]
```

And the output is the same

here's a simple code to reproduce the error

```
const {
  tensor1d,
  sequential,
  layers,
} = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const model = sequential();

  model.add(
    layers.dense({
      units: 3,
      inputShape: [3],
    })
  );

  model.compile({
    loss: 'meanSquaredError',
    optimizer: 'adam',
  });

  let inputTensor = tensor1d([1,2,3]);
  let outputTensor = tensor1d([1,2,3]);

model.fit(inputTensor, outputTensor);

let result = model.predict(inputTensor); // it fires the error here
```

The **model.fit** & **model.predict** functions both take the same input shape from **inputTensor** variable, however it fires error in the second function **model.predict**

Any explanation for that error, I'm a bit newbie in Tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

When you feed data into tensorflow model, remember the shape of input data should have batch dimension.

So your input data have to expand the dimension, like this:

```
let inputTensor = tensor1d([[1,2,3]]);
let outputTensor = tensor1d([[1,2,3]]);
```

Or use tensorflow function [`tf.expandDims`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#expandDims) to do this :

The shape of output and input tensor will be (1,3).

**The error message means you feed 3 data with 1 dimension, but model expect 3 dimension.**